# Laravel 10 - hasOne with a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-relations

I have 3 tables:

users

- id
- name

place

- id
- name

place_waiter_pivot

- user_id
- place_id

One place can have many users (waiters), but a user can be assigned only to one place (also user doesn't have to be a waiter, so he will not belong to any place in this case).

So far I have this relations written, but they don't work. What am I doing wrong here?

**Place model:**

```
public function waiters(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, 'place_waiter_pivot');
    }
```

**User model:**

```
public function waiter(): HasOneThrough
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Place::class, 'place_waiter_pivot');
    }
```

Comment: your user table needs a nullable `place_id` column, than you can create the `waiter` belongsTo `place` and `place` hasMany `waiters` relations

Comment: no matter what relationship you want in your head, your database table structure is a many-to-many relationship, why not use many-to-many?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your usage may not be appropiate for the scenario you want. So, using belongsToMany should resolve your problem.

You can try to change your code like this:

```
class Place extends Model
    {
        public function waiters(): BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'place_waiter_pivot', 'place_id', 'user_id');
        }
    }
```

And in your user model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function places(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class, 'place_waiter_pivot', 'user_id', 'place_id');
    }
}
```